# CakePHP project redirecting from localhost to live website

Tags: cakephp, virtualhost

I need to make some changes on an existing CakePHP project, but I can't run it on localhost because every time I try to access `http://localhost:8080/{name-of-project}/` it redirects me to `http://www.{name-of-project}.com`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely in your .htaccess file there is a non-www to www redirect installed.

As Adam notes, it may be useful to **clear your browser cache** when working with redirects. A cached redirect would no longer hit your server configuration so any changes you do will not be visible.

Comment: Well, i have 3 .htaccess in project directory, each one in different folder, one is in root of the directory, second one is in /app and the third is in /webroot and even when i deleted the contents of each one of them, the project still does the same thing

Comment: Im trying to run it in xampp by the way.

Comment: Ok you were right there was a redirect, chrome just cached the redirect, after i disabled cache it worked! Thanks

Comment: Ah, good idea to clear the cache, I will update the answer to include that note.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this one when Im still using cakephp2 and still duable using cakephp3

**from live .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC] 
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L] 
   RewriteRule    ^$ webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I change it to this one

**.htaccess local**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]

</IfModule>
```